# delete merge and commit in remote git repository

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control, commit

unfortunately i committed from Spring Tool Suite with default author name created by IDE. After that i changed author name with command

```
git commit --amend author="<my-correct-name> <my-correct-mail>"
```

Git creates another commit with the same changes and correct author. Then it makes me merge on master but again with default author name. Now this is the situation:
[git bash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uohN.png)
I want to keep only commit with red tick and delete the two others. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: git reset --hard HEAD~1
and 
git push --force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your HEAD to commit before

```
git checkout <name_of_commit_before_this_three_commits>
```

then add necessary commit

```
git cherry-pick 52af2ce....
```

then delete master branch

```
git branch -D master
```

then recreate master branch on your HEAD

```
git checkout -b master
```

Comment: well done, thanks...but now, how i can update remote repo on github and pull it on my IDE?

Comment: Try to 'git push -f origin master' to update remote repository